# CodeIgniter Email function is not accepting the from mail ID

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using codeigniter and using the email library to send emails.

Ref: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

```
$CI->email->initialize(array(
          'protocol' => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
          'smtp_user' => 'mymailid@gmail.com',
          'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword',
          'smtp_port' => 465,
          'crlf' => "\r\n",
          'newline' => "\r\n",
          'mailtype' => 'html',
              'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
              'wordwrap' => TRUE
        ));


        $CI->email->from('companyadmin@company.com', 'Company Admin');
        $CI->email->reply_to('companyadmin@company.com', 'Company Admin');
        $CI->email->to($to);
        $CI->email->subject($subject);
        $CI->email->message($message);
        if($attachfile!=''){
        $CI->email->attach($attachfile);
        }
```

When I send an email, I expect the From address to be 'companyadmin@company.com'. But it always uses the SMTP mail address.

```
from:   Company Admin <mymailid@gmail.com>
reply-to:   Company Admin <companyadmin@company.com>
to: reciepient@email.com
date:   Sat, Mar 14, 2015 at 5:33 PM
subject:    New password
mailed-by:  gmail.com
signed-by:  gmail.com
```

Why my mail ID is shown in the From address. how can I receive emails from mailID i desire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using google smtp and an smtp ID. If you don't want to have it there, simply use codeigniter's default mailer which relies on you web host's mailing function:

```
$this->load->helper('typography');

//Send user information and message to the administrator`s email
$data['Message'] = nl2br_except_pre($message);
$HTML_Message = $this->load->view('email_html_format', $data, true);

$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('companyadmin@company.com', 'Company Admin');
$this->email->reply_to('companyadmin@company.com', 'Company Admin');
$this->email->to($to);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($HTML_Message);
$this->email->set_alt_message(nl2br_except_pre($message));
if($attachfile!=''){
$this->email->attach($attachfile);


return $this->email->send();
```